# How to find out a^b^c^… mod m

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I would like to calculate:

### a<sup>b<sup>c<sup>d<sup>.<sup>.<sup>.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup> mod m

I know when a is coprime to m then we can easily find out the answer using  Euler's totient function. But I wish to know the ideas when a is not coprime to m.

Thanks In Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chinese Remainder Theorem. We have

$$\begin{cases}m=\gcd(a,m)\cdot m_1\\a=\gcd(a,m)\cdot a_1\\ m_1,a_1\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}a^{b^{c^{d^\ldots}}}\equiv 0\pmod {\gcd(a,m)}\\
a^{b^{c^{d^\ldots}}}\equiv a^{b^{c^{d^\ldots}}\mod {\phi(m_1)}}\equiv r \pmod{m_1}, r\neq 0\end{cases}$$

$$a^{b^{c^{d^\ldots}}}\equiv r\cdot\gcd(a,m)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\gcd(a,m)}\mod {m_1}\right)\pmod {m}$$

---

You can find more information on the Chinese Remainder Theorem (abbreviated as CRT) [here](http://nrich.maths.org/5466) and anywhere else, just google it.

Here are two ways of solving a system of $2$ linear congruences that have coprime moduli.

The first one uses the Bezout's Lemma and the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/exeucalg.html).

They are similar in the way that the $1$st one finds modular multiplicative inverses with the help of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. We have $\frac{1}{n}\equiv y\pmod m$ and $\frac{1}{m}\equiv x\pmod n$.

$$\begin{cases}a\equiv r_m\pmod m\\a\equiv r_n\pmod n\\\gcd(m,n)=1\\mx+ny=1\\a,r_m,r_n,x,y,m,n\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}\implies r_n(mx)+r_m(ny)\equiv \text{answer}\pmod {mn}$$

$$\begin{cases}a\equiv r_m\pmod m, \frac{1}{n}\equiv n''\pmod {m}\\
a\equiv r_n\pmod n, \frac{1}{m}\equiv m''\pmod n\\\gcd(m,n)=1\\a,r_m,r_n,n'',m'',m,n\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}\implies r_mnn''+r_nmm''\equiv \text{answer}\pmod {mn}$$

Comment: Bro How to find out the value of r is 2nd expression .

Comment: @monsterspy well, you said it yourself that everything is simple when $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

Comment: I think r(mod k) is equivalent to r % k !!!!!!! @mathh

Comment: @monsterspy Yes, that is how the $\mod{}$ function is defined.

Comment: Okay thanks alot Bro. .

Comment: Would you please explain this with one example , then It will be easy for me to grasp the concepts . .!!

Comment: @monsterspy first, do you know what modular multiplicative inverses are? $\frac{1}{h}\equiv g\pmod{t}$, where $hg\equiv 1\pmod t$.

Comment: No Bro. . I know only Modular Inverse . .

Comment: Modular multiplicative inverse is what you have in mind. Inverses can be multiplicative and additive, and what you have in mind is multiplicative. Additive inverse of $j$ is just $-j$.

Comment: Okay Bro . . :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a description of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Still haven't added any examples, though. You can add in some numbers and see why all the facts are true yourself.

Comment: Okay, Now I got it too. . thanks for giving your specious time to help me . . @mathh